Best Desktop, Open ChatGPT client / gui
I am using chatGPT 4plus and am happy with it. However, the web environment is crappy.
It lacks many features here are some examples:

search being most important amongst them. It is annoying to scroll through questions to find something you asked a week ago;
It is impossible to keep track of history. Furthermore if you are interested in categorizing questions, this is impossible.
For long questions, at times it forces me to type blind as it does not show what I write.
It from time to time freezes, which I guess cannot be avoided if you keep idle for long or they have too much load. But if it does, what you were typing at the time disappears and you have to write it again
The use of space to read/write can be at times suboptimal

What would be the best desktop app/gui prefferably suppothat could run chatGPT, save all my questions LOCALY for posterity, preferably be open, and would solve all/most of these issues?
If you do not have such in mind, what is the best close in your mind?
I have done a small search and this list found, https://github.com/billmei/every-chatgpt-gui which lists some desktop apps but I do not kno if it is complete and most importantly I am not sure what is best:
Chatbox | [download][1] | [source][2]
ChatGPT menubar app | [source][3]
Clipboard Conqueror | source[4]
GPTextual | source[5]
Marvin | download[6] | source[7]

